# I want to extend my disk patition for ubuntu (dual booted ubuntu and windows)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

So I want to extend my disk space for ubuntu 16.04
I shrinked the disk for windows in Windows 10 disk manager and now I want to add that unallocated partition to my ubuntu partition. But I don't know how. I don't know how to move stuff and I don't want to break my computer at the same time. Can anyone help me?

Also I can't seem to understand the other posts, if anyone says you can go to this other post. Because I did see every other posts that I could've found about this.

[image: GParted screenshot]

Comment: The little key icons mean you are running gparted from your install. You cannot edit partitions you using, so you must use live installer and then use gparted. You may still have to swap off on swap as live installer usually mounts swap also. You also have to have unallocated inside the extended partition, yours currently is before the extended, so first have to move start of extended partition to include unallocated. Be sure to back up before any major system change or edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

The use of an extended partition (sda3) makes this a little difficult. I'll outline the easiest way first, and we can add more to the procedure if we have to.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower part of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot the a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- right-click on /dev/sda5 in the lower pane and select `swapoff`
- right-click on /dev/sda3 in the lower pane and select **move/resize**
- **resize** the left side of /dev/sda3 all the way left
- right-click on /dev/sda5 in the lower pane and select **move/resize**
- **move** /dev/sda5 all the way left
- right-click on /dev/sda6 in the lower pane and select **move/resize**
- **resize** the left side of /dev/sda6 all the way left
- if it all looks correct, then click the green "Apply" icon to do the work
- quit `gparted`
- reboot